# How to use Keras model.predict function with split inputs

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to run Keras model.predict function for my Keras model which takes two sepearate set of inputs. 21 for one layer and 7 inputs for the concatenated layer. My data is stored in a numpy array. So I am trying to use the predict function like this. Here is the code:

```
input1 = np.array([])
input2 = np.array([])
for i in trainX[0,:21]:
  np.append(input1,i)
for i in trainX[0,21:]:
  np.append(input2,i)
# inputs = np.array([input1,input2])
q = model.predict(input1,input2)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-53-ea6beb48f560> in <module>
     11   np.append(input2,i)
     12 # inputs = np.array([input1,input2])
---> 13 q = model_without_average.predict(input1,input2)
     14 # q = model.predict( np.array( [trainX[0,:21],trainX[0,21:]] ))
     15 # print(q)

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   2046             callbacks.on_predict_batch_end(end_step, {'outputs': batch_outputs})
   2047       if batch_outputs is None:
-> 2048         raise ValueError('Unexpected result of `predict_function` '
   2049                          '(Empty batch_outputs). Please use '
   2050                          '`Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or '

ValueError: Unexpected result of `predict_function` (Empty batch_outputs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.
```

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this error ?

Comment: Can you please advise about the definition of `trainX`?

Comment: @learner I did print (trainX). It prints out like this :                                                            [[ 0.86929321 -0.63508183  0.22569026 ...  0.72165745  0.98875093
   0.87667835]
 [ 0.90754211  0.32914728  0.35941187 ...  0.77973217  0.99235576
   0.79834259]
 ....]. Basically it's. a numpy array having 28 columns and 1000000 rows (instances).

Comment: The error you presented does not seem to be the result of your code snippet. That would be helpful to provide a minimum reproducible example -- https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example